# Ubuntu mate 16.04 won't boot into GUI anymore

Tags: boot

I've had this problem a couple of times now on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3.  The pi won't boot into the GUI and I believe goes into emergency mode.  Originally there were some issues where the kernel couldn't boot the `lp`, `ppdev`, and `parport-pc` modules so I commented them out from the `cups-filters.conf` file.  Those errors then no longer appeared in the journalctl log.  However, I am still having issues and the only error that is remaining is the following:

> brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code

Not really sure if this is what is left that is preventing the boot up into the GUI and how to resolve this issue so would appreciate any help anyone can provide. [The full journalctl log can be found here on pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/Bj5F6Hx9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.  After I commented out the modules in cups-filters.conf, I removed any drives that I had manually added to fstab and then did a fsck -y against the root drive.  After that everything boots in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "The pi won't boot into the GUI and I believe goes into maintenance mode"? Can you describe your environment better?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant emergency mode.  not maintenance mode.